# $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{t-z_0}dt=$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We are given $z_0 \in \mathbb C - \mathbb R$ (meaning $z_0$ has an imaginary component. it is not real).

Show that if $Im(z_0)>0$ then $\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{t-z_0}dt=\frac{1}{2}$, and it is equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ if $Im(z_0)<0$.

What I tried:

$\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{t-z_0}dt=\lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\ln|t-z_0|)_{-R}^{R}=\lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\ln|R-z_0|-\ln|-R-z_0|)=\lim_{R \to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\ln|\frac{R-z_0}{-R-z_0}|$

I am unsure where to go from here. Maybe define $z_0=a+bi$ and actually see what $|\frac{R-z_0}{-R-z_0}|$ is?

Comment: this integral diverges...

Comment: Yes.  Write $z_0 = x_0+iy_0$, compute real and imaginary parts of $1/(t-z_0)$.  Integrate.  The integral for the imaginary part has an arctan in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can carry out this integration without direct appeal to real analysis.  That is, we need not split the integral into real and imaginary parts.  Rather, we [cut the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane#Cutting_the_plane) to uniquely define the log function.

> NOTE:
>
> The choice of branch cut is not unique.  In fact, any contour that starts at $z_0$ and terminates at the [point at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity) suffices here.

To that end, we cut the plane parallel to the real axis, starting at $z_0$ and ending at $(-\infty,\text{Im}(z_0))$.  Then, the integral of interest can be written

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-R}^R \frac{1}{t-z_0}\,dt&=\log(R-z_0)-\log(-R-z_0)\\\\
&=\log \left(\frac{|R-z_0|}{|R+z_0|}\right)+i\left(\arg(R-z_0)-\arg(-R-z_0)\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

where $-\pi < \arg(z-z_0)\le \pi$.  In arriving at $(1)$, we used

$$\log (z-z_0) =\log |z-z_0|+i\arg(z-z_0)$$

For $\text{Im}(z_0)>0$, $\lim_{R\to \infty} \arg(R-z_0)=0$ and $\lim_{R\to \infty} \arg(-R-z_0)=-\pi$.

For $\text{Im}(z_0)<0$, $\lim_{R\to \infty} \arg(R-z_0)=0$ and $\lim_{R\to \infty} \arg(-R-z_0)=\pi$.

Putting it all together, we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{t-z_0}\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\frac12 &,  \text{Im}(z_0)>0\\\\
-\frac12 &, \text{Im}(z_0)<0
\end{cases}
$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Something with the signs don't add up. you missed a $+$ somewhere.

Comment: There was a "cut-and-paste" typo that I've edited.  All should be OK now.  And thank you for the best vote!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $z_0=iy$ you can use a change of variables to obtain that,

$\int_{-R}^R{1\over{t-iy}}dt=\int_{-R}^R{{t+iy}\over{t^2+y^2}}dt$

$\int_{-R}^R{t\over{t^2+y^2}}dt =0$ since if $f(t)={t\over{t^2+y^2}}$, $f(-t)=-f(t)$

$\int_{-R}^R{y\over{t^2+y^2}}dt= Artan(R/y)-Arctan(-R/y)$ this implies that $lim_{R\rightarrow +\infty}\int_{-R}^R{y\over{t^2+y^2}}dt=\pi$ so $\int_{-R}^R{1\over{t-iy}}dt=1/2$.

Comment: Note that $z_0$ is only supposed to be non real, not necessarily purely imaginary.

Comment: As i said you can obtain this by a change of variables, the computation in the general case is almost identical

Answer (score 0):

If $z_0=a+bi$, then
$$
\frac{1}{t-z_0}=\frac{1}{t-a-bi}=\frac{t-a+bi}{(t-a)^2+b^2}
$$
Now
$$
\int_{-R}^R\frac{t-a}{(t-a)^2+b^2}\,dt=
\left[\frac{1}{2}\log((t-a)^2+b^2)\right]_{-R}^R
$$
and the limit of this is $0$.

Thus you want to compute
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{b}{(t-a)^2+b^2}\,dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\,du
$$
with the substitution $t-a=bu$. Note that the improper integral is not the limit of the integrals from $-R$ to $R$, but it exists nonetheless, so its value is the same as the limit you're looking for.
$$